# Jquery Validate plugin throws error even when required field is filled out

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the validate plugin. Problem is when I execute a .valid() it is returning an error for every required field **even when the field has a value.**. I see the console spit out stuff like this;

forms-validation.js:835 init [span#str_grade-error.has-error]

I can't seem to figure out why its throwing an error when the required prerequisite has been met.

This field is filled out.

```
function global_form_validate_this(myobj)
{
    myobj.validate({
           // States                        
        ignore: ':hidden:not([class~=selectized]),:hidden > .selectized, .selectize-control .selectize-input input',
           errorClass: "has-error",
           validClass: "has-success",
           errorElement: "span",

           // Rules

           rules: {
               firstname: {
                   required: true
               },
            dte_user_birthday:
            {
              required: true,
              date: true
            },
            dte_tetnus:
            {
              date: true
            },
            dte_tb_test:
            {
              date: true
            },
            dte_mmr:
            {
              date: true
            },  
            dte_dpt:
            {
              date: true
            },  
            dte_hepb:
            {
              date: true
            },  
            dte_hepa3:
            {
              date: true
            },  
            dte_IPV:
            {
              date: true
            },  
            dte_Meningococcal:
            {
              date: true
            },  
            dte_HIB:
            {
              date: true
            },      
            dte_PCV:
            {
              date: true
            },                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            str_credit_card_number:
            {
              required: true,
              creditcard: true
            },                          
            dte_season_start:
            {
              required: true,
              date: true
            },
            dte_season_end:
            {
              required: true,
              date: true
            },      
            int_win_point_value:
            {
              required: true,
              integer: true
            },          
            int_loss_point_value:
            {
              required: true,
              integer: true
            },          
            int_tie_point_value:
            {
              required: true,
              integer: true
            },                                                                                                                                              
               agree: {
                   required: true
               },       
               terms: {
                   required: true
               },                               
               username: {
                   required: true
               },   
               combo: {
                   required: true
               },   
            str_league_email: {
                   required: true,
                   email: true
               },   
            howmuchnow: {
                   required: true,
                   // money: true
               },                                                           
            str_organization_email: {
                   required: true,
                   email: true
               },   
            str_frontdesk_email: {
                   required: true,
                   email: true
               },               
            str_email: {
                   required: true,
                   email: true
               },   
            email: {
                   required: false,
                   email: true
               },                                                                                   
               city: {
                   required: true
               },                                   
               useremail: {
                   required: true,
                   email: true
               },
               str_email_current: {
                   required: true,
                   email: true
               },                               
               website: {
                   required: true,
                   url: true
               },
               language: {
                   required: true
               },
               upload1: {
                   required: true,
                   extension: "jpg|png|gif|jpeg|doc|docx|pdf|xls|rar|zip"
               },
            str_email_current_check: 
            {
                equalTo: '#str_email_current'
            },              
               inputname: {
                   required: true
               },
               comment: {
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 30
               },
               security_code: {
                   required: true,
                integer: true,
                   minlength: 6
               },                           
               mobile_phone: {
                   require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
               },
               home_phone: {
                   require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
               },
               password: {
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 4
               },
               str_ccv_number: {
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 3
               },                                                                                   
               repeatPassword: {
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 4,
                   equalTo: '#password'
               },
               zip: {
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 5
               },       
               team: {
                   required: false,
                   minlength: 5
               },               
               fname: {
                   required: false,
                   minlength: 2
               },               
               lname: {
                   required: false,
                   minlength: 2
               },                                                                                                   
               mobile: {
                   required: true
               },
               mobile1: {
                   required: true
               },
               verification: {
                   required: true,
                   smartCaptcha: 19
               },
               applicant_age: {
                   required: true,
                   min: 16
               },
               int_agegroup_max: {
                   required: true,
                   max: 98
               },                           
               licence_no: {
                   required: function(element) {
                       return $("#applicant_age").val() > 19;
                   }
               },
               child_name: {
                   required: "#parents:checked"
               }

           },

           /* @validation error messages
            ---------------------------------------------- */

           messages: {
               firstname: {
                   required: 'Enter first name'
               },
               agree: {
                   required: 'You must check this box.'
               },
               terms: {
                   required: 'You must check this box.'
               },                               
               lastname: {
                   required: 'Enter last name'
               },
               city: {
                   required: 'Please enter a valid city.'
               },               
               useremail: {
                   required: 'Enter email address',
                   email: 'Enter a VALID email address'
               },
               website: {
                   required: 'Enter your website URL',
                   url: 'URL should start with - http://www'
               },
               language: {
                   required: 'Select language'
               },
               upload1: {
                   required: 'Please select file',
                   extension: 'File format not supported'
               },
               inputname: {
                   required: 'Please select model'
               },
               comment: {
                   required: 'Add comments please.',
                   minlength: 'Enter at least 30 characters or more'
               },
               mobile_phone: {
                   require_from_group: 'Add a mobile number'
               },
               security_code: {
                   required: 'Enter a six digit NUMERICAL security code.',
                minlength: 'Enter a six digit NUMERICAL security code.',
                integer: 'Enter a six digit NUMERICAL security code.'
               },                           
               home_phone: {
                   require_from_group: 'Add a phone number'
               },
               password: {
                   required: 'Please enter password'
               },
               repeatPassword: {
                   required: 'Please repeat password',
                   equalTo: 'Password does not match'
               },
               mobile: {
                   required: 'Please select model'
               },
               mobile1: {
                   required: 'Please select model'
               },
               verification: {
                   required: 'Please enter correct number',
                   smartCaptcha: 'Wrong number. Please recalculate'
               },
               applicant_age: {
                   required: 'Enter age',
                   min: 'Must be 16 years or above'
               },
               licence_no: {
                   required: 'Enter licence number'
               },
               int_agegroup_max: {
                   required: 'Enter age',
                   max: 'Please enter a valid age range.'
               },                           
               child_name: {
                   required: 'Child name not entered'
               }

           },

           /* @validation highlighting + error placement
            ---------------------------------------------------- */

           highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
               $(element).parent().addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);                
           },
           unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
               $(element).parent().removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);                
           },           
          errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
          {
            if($(".has-error").length > 0){
                $('.accordion_missing_data').show();
            }                                                                   
                        console.log(error);
            // qTip call
            if (!$(element).hasClass('valid')) {
              if (error.html() != "") {
                $(element).parent().qtip({
                  content: {
                    text: error.html()
                  },
                    style: {
                        width: 200,
                        classes: 'qtip-red tip-tipped',
                        tip: true
                    },  
                  position: {
                    my: 'bottom center',
                    at: 'top center',
                    target: $(element)
                  },
                  show: {
                    when: false,
                    ready: true
                  },
                  hide: false
                });
              }
            }
          },
          success: function(label, element) {
            // Hide tooltips on valid elements
            $(element).not('.error').qtip('hide');
          } 

       });              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by fields that were inside a hidden div but not necessarily hidden themselves (display:none) on the input itself. Thus even though it was not visible to the browser it was visible to the validator.